# Scrapinghub Deploy Failed

Tags: scrapy, scrapinghub

I am trying to deploy a project to scrapinghub and here's the error I am getting

```
slackclient 1.3.2 has requirement websocket-client<0.55.0,>=0.35, but you have websocket-client 0.57.0.
Warning: Pip checks failed, please fix the conflicts.
WARNING: There're some errors when doing pip-check:
  WARNING: The scripts pip, pip3 and pip3.8 are installed in '/app/python/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
{"message": "Dependencies check exit code: 1", "details": "Pip checks failed, please fix the conflicts", "error": "requirements_error"}

{"status": "error", "message": "Requirements error"}
Deploy log location: /var/folders/p7/nwmq6_4138n6t3w2spdnpzfm0000gn/T/shub_deploy_5l9k3_nm.log
Error: Deploy failed: b'{"status": "error", "message": "Requirements error"}'
```

I can't figure out how to find the log file its saying?

Comment: The first line is quite specific: `slackclient 1.3.2 has requirement websocket-client<0.55.0,>=0.35, but you have websocket-client 0.57.0.`. You should solve that conflict in your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently and the cause was that the stack I was using on the dash required specific, older versions of packages that were dependencies of ones in my requirements.

A good first step is to try installing the older version of websocket-client. If slackclient 1.3.2 works on the older version you;re good, otherwise you might need to try rolling back slackclient too.